# is there any reason to use tagocity, now that you have categories in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

you can now tag an email with a category and give it multiple categories.  is there any reason to use tagocity with outlook 2007 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tag messages with good keyboard shortcut. I am not sure if this is available in outlook.

That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: In Outlook 2007 you can assign the shortcuts CTRL-F2 to CTRL-F12 to categories. See also http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA100141501033.aspx